# Why does Smarty replace things like '%>' with <?php echo '%>'; ?> and how to avoid this?

Tags: php, smarty

Im optimizing a Smarty template and things are looking good but the only thing left is that the resulting cached template is littered with things like `<?php echo '%>'; ?>` where it should just have `'%>'`.

It does the same for `'?>'` but that's understandable as it would confuse PHP, does `'%>'` have the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, it does the same for the more traditional closing tag `?>`.

Well, `%>` is a PHP closing tag too, albeit one disabled by default. You'd activate it with [asp-tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php):

> Enables the use of ASP-like <% %> tags
>   in addition to the usual tags. This
>   includes the variable-> value printing
>   shorthand of <%= $value %>. For more
>   information, see Escaping from HTML.

Smarty's just being thorough. Unfortunately, it's not doing a very good job of it. Make sure that this is disabled and your problems should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [asp-tags ini setting:](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

> asp_tags boolean
>
> Enables the use of ASP-like <% %> tags in addition to the usual  tags. This includes the variable-> value printing shorthand of <%= $value %>. For more information, see Escaping from HTML.

In newer php versions this is turned off by default so if smarty changes those i wouldn't be surprised. (If i understood you correctly)